# Is there a way to fill up the delay of useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make a simple animation, but when the animation ends there is literally a split second that is showing the old values of opacitate & translate.Is there a way that i can make that dissapper?

I've tried to use useRef and re-render the component but no luck.Ignore the timeout functionz

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

const Titlu = () => {
  let [opacitate, setOpacitate] = useState(0);

  let [translate, setTranslate] = useState(-30);

  function Schimba() {
    setOpacitate(prevOpacity => prevOpacity = 1);
    setTranslate(prevTranslate => prevTranslate = 20);
  }

  function timeout(timp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className="Part1">
      <h1 className="ForkyTitlu" 
          onAnimationEnd={Schimba} 
          style={{
            opacity:opacitate, 
            transform: `translate(${translate}%, 0%)`
          }} >
        <span className ="Forky">Forky</span>
        <span className ="Nutrition">Nutrition</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Titlu />);
```

```css
.Part1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
  border-bottom: 3px black;
}

.ForkyTitlu {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3vw;
  /*
    margin-left: 12vw;
    margin-top: 40vh;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    */
  animation-name: titluAnimation;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes titluAnimation {
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
}

.Forky {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px #0000009c;
}

.Nutrition {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px orange;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `onAnimationEnd` calls `Schimba`, the animation is over, and the CSS values are resettled top their original values. This is the gap you're seeing.

However, you don't really need a state. Move all animation related properties, including the initial state to the animation:

```
@keyframes titluAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-30%);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
}
```

And define the [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) (I've used the `animation` shorthand) to be `forwards`:

```
animation: titluAnimation 2s forwards;
```

> *forwards*
>
> The target will retain the computed values set by the last keyframe encountered during execution.

```js
const Titlu = () => (
  <div className = "Part1">
    <h1 className = "ForkyTitlu">
      <span className ="Forky">Forky</span>
      <span className ="Nutrition">Nutrition</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Titlu />);
```

```css
.Part1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-bottom: 50vh;
  border-bottom: 3px black;
}

.ForkyTitlu {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3vw;
  animation: titluAnimation 2s forwards;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes titluAnimation {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-30%);
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(20%);
  }
}

.Forky {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px #0000009c;
}

.Nutrition {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px orange;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you want/need to use state to control the animation, it's better to define the start/end states as classes, toggle them with the state, and use CSS transition to animate the change.

Example - click the Toggle button to see the animation:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Titlu = () => {
  const [start, setState] = useState(true);
  
  const toggleStart = () => setState(s => !s);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className = "Part1">
        <h1 className = {`ForkyTitlu ${start ? 'start' : 'end'}`}>
          <span className ="Forky">Forky</span>
          <span className ="Nutrition">Nutrition</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <button onClick={toggleStart}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Titlu />);
```

```css
.Part1 {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 3px black;
}

.ForkyTitlu {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3vw;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.ForkyTitlu.start {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-30%);
}

.ForkyTitlu.end {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(20%);
}

.Forky {
  color: black;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px #0000009c;
}

.Nutrition {
  color: orange;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-shadow: -30px 15px 30px orange;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```